# Android: Google Maps V2: How do we get the longitude/latitude of the screen?

Tags: android, google-maps

We are using Google Maps V1 and we start to migrate to Google Maps V2.
Now we need to obtaing the CENTER, the Radius and the Box of the Screen, to get some points in the middle of the screen and a radius which covers everything.

In Google Maps for Android v1, MapView had a convenience method:  getMapCenter(). Now I cannot figure out how to get map center with v2 of this api. I have perused the API documentation, but there is no mention of such a feature.

I need to get Latitude/Longitude span. I used MapView.getLatitudeSpan() and MapView.getLongitudeSpan() in version 1 APIs. Now I can't find something like this in V2.

Does anybody have the same problem?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.html#target

Comment: There are TONS of posts, tutorials, question/answers, forums, etc. that will teach you how to do this... Google is your friend (in this case especially).

Comment: I think everyone else already upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

From a GoogleMap object , call getProjection() which will return a Projection object with which you can call getVisableRegion() which should contain all the info you need.

Please see the following:

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getProjection%28%29

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach is using CameraPosition.

```
mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude;
mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target.longitude;
```

Here is the doc which describe [CameraPosition](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition#developer-guide)